# node js app.use throws a middleware functions

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node.js i am following blog and practicing how to create a new blog

https://vegibit.com/node-js-blog-tutorial/

Till this steps everything works fine "Edge Template Engine With Express" , once i added the below lines

```js
app.use(expressEdge);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

I am getting the below error.

> C:\Automation\NodeJS_Projects-master\nodejs-blog-tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210
> throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
> ^
>
> TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
> at Function.use (C:\Automation\NodeJS_Projects-master\nodejs-blog-tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210:11)
> at Object. (C:\Automation\NodeJS_Projects-master\nodejs-blog-tutorial\index.js:8:5)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

## Full code tried to far

```js
    const express = require('express');
    var slash = require("slash");
    const expressEdge = require('express-edge');
    const app = new express();
    var dirname = __dirname;
    if (process.platform === 'win32') dirname = slash(dirname);
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(expressEdge);
    app.set('views', dirname + '/views');
    
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/node-blog', { useNewUrlParser: true })
        .then(() => 'You are now connected to Mongo!')
        .catch(err => console.error('Something went wrong', err))
        
    app.get('/posts/new', (req, res) => {
        res.render('create')
    });
     
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('index');
    });
    
    app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
        global.__base = dirname + '/pages/about.html';
        console.log(global.__base)
        res.sendFile(global.__base);
    });
    
    app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
        global.__base = dirname + '/pages/contact.html';
        res.sendFile(global.__base);
    });
     
    app.get('/post', (req, res) => {
        global.__base = dirname + '/pages/post.html';
        res.sendFile(global.__base);
    });
    
    app.listen(4000, () => {
        console.log('App listening on port 4000')
    });
```

Comment: I am trying the above code in windows environment

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: C:\Automation\NodeJS_Projects-master\nodejs-blog-tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
    ^

TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
    at Function.use (C:\Automation\NodeJS_Projects-master\nodejs-blog-tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Automation\NodeJS_Projects-master\nodejs-blog-tutorial\index.js:8:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)

Comment: {
  "name": "nodejs-blog-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "create a blog using node.js",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "blog"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-edge": "^2.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.23",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "slash": "^3.0.0",
    "startbootstrap-clean-blog": "^5.0.9"
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial might be outdated as they seem to use an older version of `express-edge`, since you should set up `express-edge` as follows (see https://github.com/ecrmnn/express-edge#usage for more details):

```
const { engine } = require('express-edge');
...
app.use(engine); // instead of app.use(expressEdge);
```

Alternatively you can do:

```
const expressEdge = require('express-edge');
...
app.use(expressEdge.engine);
```

If you take a look at the [source](https://github.com/ecrmnn/express-edge/blob/master/dist/index.js#L59), you can see that the module exports an object (containing `config` and `engine`) and no middleware, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your pointing out the right error and also pointing the solution

Comment: Happy to help :) Please accept the answer if it solved the problem, thank you.

Comment: @MageshBalasubramaniam Alternatively you can modify your existing code and do `app.use(expressEdge.engine)`